# OpenVPN config file not started automatically, works when running manually

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, systemctl

On my Ubuntu 16.04 server, I have three different openvpn conf files in /etc/openvpn: `server_tcp.conf`, `server_udp.conf` and `server_ptp.conf`. All work when starting manually, e.g.:

`sudo openvpn server_ptp.conf`

However, when running `sudo systemctl start openvpn`, only `server_tcp` and `server_udp` are started.

Comment: What is your question? It can be "why?" or "how to make all of them start?", or something else. These are different questions. Please be specific.

Comment: The question was both of the above.